# If my ox gores an androgynous, am i liable?

Tags: halacha, animals, mishpatim, androgynous

(Playing devil's advocate with this question.)

In Shmot 21:31, [Rashi says](http://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.21.31):

> לפי שנאמר והמית איש או אשה, יכול אינו חיב אלא על הגדולים, תלמוד לומר או בן יגח וגו' , לחייב על הקטנים כגדולים:

The Torah has to specify that it's both male and female, adult and child, that you're liable for goring.

But what about an androgynous (person with both male and female parts)? If my ox gores them, am i liable?

The case of a *tumtum* seems clear that you'd be liable, because there the person is either definitely male or definitely female, we just aren't sure which.

And if the answer is an obvious yes, please provide sources. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mechilta has a special Drasha to include a tumtum and androgen. אין לי אלא בן גמור ובת גמורה טומטום ואנדרוגינוס מניין ת׳ל או בן יגח או בת יגח.

The Torah Temimah on the passuk #232 explains that the word או connotes a situation of uncertainty.
יתכן דדריש או בן או בת אף כזה שהוא ספק בן או בת דהיינו טומטום ואנדרוגינוס.